# Tezos-client can't import TCP signer

Tags: tezos-client, baking-node, tezos-signer

For my baking operation, I have set up a remote signer and SSH tunneled it to my baking server on port 7878. I have also set up `tezos-signer` with `--require-authentication`.

On my baking server, I'm now trying to add it with the recommended command:

```
./tezos-client import secret key my_signer tcp://localhost:7878/tz1abcdef123456789
```

`tezos-client` just hangs and does not give me the prompt back unless I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. How can I even start debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a simple mistake; I had already imported another TCP tezos-signer on the same port (7878). Apparently `tezos-client` does not fail gracefully when trying to import a different address on a port that's already registered with one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the exact same thing successfully.

> I have set up a remote signer and SSH tunneled it to my baking server on port 7878.

It sounds from your description, and the symptom you describe, like you might have done your tunnelling backwards. The remote signer shouldn't initiate any tcp connections to your baking node. The remote signer's firewall should however be configured to accept connections from your baker (whitelist the baker's IP address) on the port you've setup your signer to run on, port 7878.

This is to say you need to configure the firewall of your remote signer for this, not the firewall for your baker.